# File Not Found when starting spark application via REST

Tags: tomcat7, apache-spark

I have one spark web application which I am trying to deploy on tomcat. But when I am trying to start spark using REST calls it gives the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 
 file:/home/user/checkpoint/941ed8d5-85ce-423d-9286-8caae2f92d5e does not exist.
```

I have properly set the checkpoint directory and its working properly in local mode

Comment: Suggested a new title and broke the error line in two so no scrolling is needed. Frankly, the filename is immaterial... the problem is likely to be the path itself.

Answer (score 0):

It was some permission issue. Spark is running from some other user account and tomcat from other. So there was some permission issue.